# Recomendations for Discrete Graphics Linux Laptop of Thinkpad Build Quality

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards

I'm currently looking for a laptop with discrete graphics that will work properly with Linux. I would like to avoid optimus as it never works right, and doesn't put things on the gpu when I want them on there.

I would probably end up buying a used laptop (within the last 2 years), that's currently a good deal. I usually just buy thinkpads, and I would like to get something similar.

I'm currently rocking a w540, and the only thing holding it back is the weak graphics and optimus.

Comment: Hello there. Most Thinkpads don't have discrete graphics. I'd check out for an X1 Extreme? Another choice would be the Dell XPS 15 line. I suggest checking used around your area and reviews on their Linux compatibility.

Comment: If you've buying anything new with an nVidia GPU closed sourced drivers are a must - does it matter for you?

Comment: There's a lot of range here, plenty of laptops support discreet GPUs. **What are you using this laptop for?** Are you looking for more thin and light or pure power? What's your budget? Do you specifically need AMD or Nvidia, OpenCL or CUDA? Do you plan you use your laptop at a desk as well? How much storage do you need? Do you want to dual boot?